# Self-signed EV SSL certificate

Tags: ssl, localhost

I have a ton of testing projects going on in my localhost apache server. I have SSL installed on my localhost. Call me a freak (and I wouldn't mind it because this is totally pointless), but I would like my localhost's SSL to be an EV SSL with the green bar. So how can i make a self-signed EV/Green Bar SSL certificate for my localhost? And how can i teach my FireFox to recognize it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

You can't.
EV certificates can only be issued by some certificate agencies which are hard coded inside the browser.

Comment: Technically, you can roll your own cert bundle by forking the browser.

Comment: @DeerHunter:  Sure, you could also change the source code of the browser to show the green bar whenever you like. But that probably wasn't the point of the question.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Yes. It is crazy, but I want to make the browser just show the green bar.

Comment: You might also try to create a CA (and import it as trusted) with the right OID and then issue a certificate with this CA. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14705157/how-to-check-if-a-x509-certificate-has-extended-validation-switched-on which OIDs are used to detect EV.

Comment: Do you have a reference?

Comment: Here's an actual reference (showing how to build Firefox with support for your own EV cert): http://evssl-trust.sidstamm.com/firefox-evca.html